# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile' Tensorflow 2.8.2

Tags: python, tensorflow

can someone please help me with this error....I tried using tf.io.gfile instead of tf.gfile then to its not working

error shown is still the same

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**tf.gfile** is now submodule of **tf.io**, which you can use by giving an updated full alias name **[tf.io.gfile.GFile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile)**.

Please check below code for your reference:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

with open("/tmp/x", "w") as f:
  print(f.write("asdf"))
  
with tf.io.gfile.GFile("/tmp/x") as f:   # <----using tf.io.gfile.GFile
  print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
2.8.2
4
asdf
```